# How to make jquery reference dynamic html elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Below is part of a script I have which dynamically adds html input text boxes.  Each one of these input boxes should be an autofil text box.  This is the code I'm using - http://www.nodstrum.com/2007/09/19/autocompleter/. Demo is here - http://res.nodstrum.com/autoComplete/.

For the above example it is only one input box but my code allows for dynamic input text boxes (i.e. the user clicks on a button and more pop up).

The problem I have is I don't know how to fix the jquery so that it's dynamic for the input text box id.  How do I make it dynamic so that fill() outputs data to foo01, foo11, foo21 etc. not just foo11?

```
<script src="jquery-1.2.1.pack.js" type="text/javascript">
function lookup(inputString) {
    if(inputString.length == 0) {
        // Hide the suggestion box.
        $('#suggestions').hide();
    } else {
        $.post("rpc.php", {queryString: ""+inputString+""}, function(data){
            if(data.length >0) {
                $('#suggestions').show();
                $('#autoSuggestionsList').html(data);
            }
        });
    }
} // lookup


function fill(thisValue) {
    $('#foo11').val(thisValue);
    setTimeout("$('#suggestions').hide();", 200);
}

</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
var x = 1;

function add() {
    var fooId = "foo";

    for (i=1; i<=2; i++)) {

        var element = document.createElement("input");

        element.setAttribute("type", fooId+x+i);
        element.setAttribute("name", fooId+x+i);
        element.setAttribute("id", fooId+x+i);

        if(i==1){
              element.setAttribute("onkeyup", "lookup(this.value);");                          
              element.setAttribute("onblur","fill();");
              element.setAttribute("value", "First name");
        }
        if(i==2){
               element.setAttribute("value", "Last name");
        }


        var foo = document.getElementById("fooBar");
        foo.appendChild(element);
   }
   x++;
}
</script>
```

rpc.php

```
<?php
include_once("includes/config.php");
$conn = new mysqli("$localhost",  "$dbusername",  "$dbpass", "$db", "3306")) 
if(!$conn) {
    // Show error if we cannot connect.
    echo 'ERROR: Could not connect to the database.';
} else {
    // Is there a posted query string?
    if(isset($_POST['queryString'])) {
        $queryString = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['queryString']);

        // Is the string length greater than 0?

        if(strlen($queryString) >0) {
            // Run the query: We use LIKE '$queryString%'
            // The percentage sign is a wild-card, in my example of countries it works like this...
            // $queryString = 'Uni';
            // Returned data = 'United States, United Kindom';

            $query = $conn->query("SELECT name FROM cities WHERE name LIKE '$queryString%' LIMIT 10");
            if($query) {
                // While there are results loop through them - fetching an Object (i like PHP5 btw!).
                while ($result = $query ->fetch_object()) {
                    // Format the results, im using <li> for the list, you can change it.
                    // The onClick function fills the textbox with the result.

                    // YOU MUST CHANGE: $result->value to $result->your_colum
                    echo '<li onClick="fill(\''.$result->name.'\');">'.$result->name.'</li>';
                    }
            } else {
                echo 'ERROR: There was a problem with the query.';
            }
        } else {
            // Dont do anything.
        } // There is a queryString.
    } else {
        echo 'There should be no direct access to this script!';
    }
}
?>
```

*************************EDIT********************************

It needs to be filled individually.  It looks like this:

```
Text Box (foo00)               Text Box
Add
```

If you click on Add you get

```
Text Box (foo00)               Text Box
Text Box (foo10)               Text Box
Add
```

If I was to click on text box (0,0) and started typing "Lo" a text box would pop up with London, Logon etc.  Then if you click on "London", only (0,0) will be updated and will now be "London" i.e.

```
London                  Text Box
Text Box                Text Box
Add
```

Now I click on the text box below London (foo10) and start typing "Ro" and a text box would pop up with Rome, Romania etc.  I click on Rome and only foo10 should be updated and will look like this:

```
London                  Text Box
Rome                    Text Box
Add
```

Hopefully that helps with the questions below.

I've never used jquery before this example.  I'm using jQuery 1.2.1 because that's what the example said.  I'll need to look into a newer version of JQuery.

********************** *EDIT 2* ************************************

I didn't realise that the file rpc.php called fill(), which is where I believe the issue to be.  I've updated the code above to include rpc.php and the jquery which calls it.

Comment: Are you filling all those inputs with just 1 source of value or different value for each input?

Comment: Let me get this straight: you want that when one of those `n` inputs blurs, all the others are filled with the same data?

Comment: Why not pass the name of the `input` as an argument into the `fill` function?  Something like: `element.setAttribute("onblur","fill(" + fooId+x+i + ");");`  and `function fill(name, thisValue) {...`. That's if you want to do each one independently.  If you want to fill all of them at once, set `class="foos"` on them and then use the following jquery selector: `$('.foos')`

Comment: Also, why are you using jQuery 1.2.1?

Comment: @Moshe Katz, tried that and it didn't work.  Can you give me a bit more detail as I'm really new to jquery and might not have missed something.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>In the following function, you have hard coded the id `foo11`</strike>

```
function fill(thisValue) {
    $('#foo11').val(thisValue);
    setTimeout("$('#suggestions').hide();", 200);
}
```

Instead, you can use `this` operator to access the specific textbox that called the `fill()` method.

```
function fill(this) {
    $(this).val(thisValue); // will access the current element but not sure where you are getting the value 
    setTimeout("$('#suggestions').hide();", 200);
}
```

and change the `onblur` like this

```
element.setAttribute("onblur","fill(this);");
```

After reading your updated question, I tried to make a sample application but unfortunately I can't make it to work without changing too much. The problem is, the method you are using to create auto complete works in a way that it is difficult to make it work with dynamically added HTML. So here are my 2 alternatives.

1. Make some changes in the rpc.php code and only emit values as array and create HTML on the client.
2. Since you are already using jQuery, try jQuery autocomplete 
   You can find info about autocomplete [here](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) and [here](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) 
   I already made a sample for you using jQuery autocomplete. Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fG7VW/)

Comment: Tried that and couldn't get it to work.  I'm an absolute beginner with jquery, #foo11 is the id for one of the text boxes, wouldn't the "this" have to reference the id as opposed to just being "this"?

Comment: I made an edit to my answer, please see. In jQuery `$()` takes either a CSS selector (like Id, className etc) or a DOM element (like this) and returns a jQuery object that you can use to set value. BTW, are you getting anything in `thisValue`?

Comment: Sorry comet, I've updated my code to reflect rpc.php which I didn't realize called fill().  This is where I think the issue is, with this call.